# Cannot insert and print out linked list

Tags: c++11

I'm trying to create a simple linked list class. The program runs but it gives me wrong output. And it seems like linked list doesn't insert the new nodes as I want.

```cpp
class Node
{
public:
    std::string name;
    Node *next;
};

class ProductName
{
private:
    Node *head;
public:
    ProductName()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }
    void insertNode(std::string input)
    {
        Node *temp;
        temp = new Node;
        temp->name = input;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    void printOut()
    {
        Node *p;
        p = head;
        while (p->next != NULL)
        {
            std::cout << p->name << " ";
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    ProductName object;
    object.insertNode("Hello");
    object.insertNode("world!");
    object.printOut();
}
```

I expect the output is `Hello world!`, but it prints out a string of random character `005C4BA0`

Edit: I forgot the pointer... It's `p->name` not `p` in the print function. However, now my result is `world!`.

Comment: Why don't you debug it?

Comment: Hint: Check the order of insertion

Comment: `while (p->next != NULL)` What should happen if your list is empty? What should happen if it has one element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First issue:** your are always inserting into the beginning by replacing the `head`. If you expect your nodes to appears in order of insertion you should insert them in the end:

```
class ProductName
{
private:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail; // additional member to track the last node
public:
    ProductName()
        : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr)
    { }

    void insertNode(std::string input)
    {
        Node *temp = new Node{ std::move(input), nullptr };
        if (tail) {
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
        } else {
            head = tail = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

**Second issue:** your are printing all the elements that have `next` which means that the last element won't be printed.

```
void printOut()
{
    Node *p = head;
    // print while p != nullptr
    // this also properly handles the empty list when head == nullptr
    while (p)
    {
        std::cout << p->name << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```